# actionscript - testing actionscript via command line

Tags: actionscript, command-line, syntax, console, testing

I would like to know if is there any easy way to test actionscript by using some kind of application like ruby's irb or javasctip spidermonkey where you can just open up your terminal and type the code straight away.
This would be a good time saver when speaking of actionscript, since to test some syntaxes, classes, etc. you would need to compile it via fsch.

But still not a good option just for quick testing, etc...

Answer (score 0):

> ### Duplicate Answer By Duplicate User
>
> > Please Flag User:
> >
> > > Gama11

I have used [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org) in some of my projects where automated builds were necessary: FlashDevelop has always utilized .Net and [haXe](https://haxe.org) an open source complier for AS 2.0 and later AS 3.0 ...

Flash Develop will utilize haXe in a command line fashion: within the project settings you are able to modify this command set or deploy manually once the windows based platform has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use NotePad++ to write down and save parts of my code so I can see it clearly. It does contain Actionscript in the "Languages", and it is plain and easy to use. But I am not sure how much it checks for mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that writing and compiling in flash is the easiest way. If you have a syntax error it will tell you.